# Is this some type of malware?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, malware, rootkit

I ran `chkrootkit` on my Linux Mint system, and it complained about several processes like this one:

> scott    31745  0.0  0.3 1206060 120352 ?      Sl   Oct03   0:15
>   /usr/share/atom/atom --type=renderer
>   --enable-experimental-web-platform-features --no-sandbox --service-pipe-token=2CF17518423016539EFC7319BDF1BA74 --lang=en-US --app-path=/usr/share/atom/resources/app.asar --node-integration=true --webview-tag=true --no-sandbox --context-id=2 --enable-pinch --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --content-image-texture-target=0,0,3553;0,1,3553;0,2,3553;0,3,3553;0,4,3553;0,5,3553;0,6,3553;0,7,3553;0,8,3553;0,9,3553;0,10,3553;0,11,3553;0,12,3553;0,13,3553;0,14,3553;0,15,3553;0,16,3553;0,17,3553;1,0,3553;1,1,3553;1,2,3553;1,3,3553;1,4,3553;1,5,3553;1,6,3553;1,7,3553;1,8,3553;1,9,3553;1,10,3553;1,11,3553;1,12,3553;1,13,3553;1,14,3553;1,15,3553;1,16,3553;1,17,3553;2,0,3553;2,1,3553;2,2,3553;2,3,3553;2,4,3553;2,5,3553;2,6,3553;2,7,3553;2,8,3553;2,9,3553;2,10,3553;2,11,3553;2,12,3553;2,13,3553;2,14,3553;2,15,3553;2,16,3553;2,17,3553;3,0,3553;3,1,3553;3,2,3553;3,3,3553;3,4,3553;3,5,3553;3,6,3553;3,7,3553;3,8,3553;3,9,3553;3,10,3553;3,11,3553;3,12,3553;3,13,3553;3,14,3553;3,15,3553;3,16,3553;3,17,3553;4,0,3553;4,1,3553;4,2,3553;4,3,3553;4,4,3553;4,5,3553;4,6,3553;4,7,3553;4,8,3553;4,9,3553;4,10,3553;4,11,3553;4,12,3553;4,13,3553;4,14,3553;4,15,3553;4,16,3553;4,17,3553
>   --disable-accelerated-video-decode --disable-gpu-compositing --enable-gpu-async-worker-context --service-request-channel-token=2CF17518423016539EFC7319BDF1BA74 --renderer-client-id=5 --shared-files=v8_natives_data:100,v8_snapshot_data:101
>   --disable-accelerated-video-decode --disable-gpu-compositing --enable-gpu-async-worker-context --service-request-channel-token=2CF17518423016539EFC7319BDF1BA74 --renderer-client-id=5 --shared-files=v8_natives_data:100,v8_snapshot_data:101

Is that shellcode or something ominous I should be concerned about? The reason I ask is that I've found `chkrootkit` to not be 100% accurate on other occasions. For example, it tells me that my `tcpd` is infected, and I don't even have that installed.

Answer (score 3):

This is the [Atom](https://atom.io/) text editor. It's built on the Electron framework, and Electron itself uses a variant of the Chrome browser as its frontend; the very long command-line you're seeing is typical for Chrome's multiprocess architecture.

If chkrootkit doesn't tell you *why* exactly it found the program unusual, and if you indeed use the Atom editor, then just ignore the warning.

On the other hand, if you do not use Atom, better figure out what process it is – check `/proc/31745/exe`, `/proc/31745/fd/`, and so on.